# Оформление цитаты с нестандартным border-radius

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте! Стоит задача сверстать такой вот блочок-цитату.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Непосредственно вопрос: можно ли, сверстать левый нижний угол цитаты чисто на css, чтобы не подгружать картинку?

```css
* {
  border-radius: box-sizing;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 50px auto;
}
.quote {
  position: relative;
  padding: 9px 10px 10px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ffb700;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 0px;
}
.quote:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -11px;
  left: -1px;
  width: 8px;
  height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">  
  <p class="quote">
    Dude is a quote here Dude is a quote here Dude is a quote here Dude is a quote here.
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например, вот так:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #39A2AE;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
.wrapper {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}
.quote {
  padding: 20px 20px 40px 20px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0
   
}
.quote:after {
  
  border: 10px solid;
  border-color: transparent #39A2AE #39A2AE transparent;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 0 #fff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  bottom: -10px;
  transform: rotate(45deg)
}
.quote:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -3px;
    left: -2px;
    width: calc(100% + 2px);
    border-left: 2px solid;
    border-top: 2px solid;
    border-radius: 30px 0 0 0;
    height: 20px;
    background: #39A2AE;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="quote">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas doloribus cumque eos debitis at distinctio consequatur necessitatibus eius odit explicabo? Consequatur nulla cumque nemo sed dolorum perspiciatis amet porro minus.
  </div>
</div>
```